# If there is a stain on your shirt are you allowed to scrub it or pour water on it in the 9 days?

Tags: nine-days, washing-clothes

This would be considered kibus (laundering) on shabbos, and hence forbidden. But is it considered laundering in the 9 days?

Comment: I once had a surface stain on my shirt and asked the Rosh Kollel if I could scratch it off and he said definitely. Not sure about scrubbing or rinsing.

Answer (score 3):

[Dinonline](https://dinonline.org/2021/07/11/spot-cleaning-during-the-nine-days/) says that it is allowed:

> Yes, you can spot clean during the nine days.  If that won’t work for
> you, you can also put a pair of (*freshly-laundered*) pants on a dirty
> floor, and stamp on it until it no longer has a fresh feel to it, and
> then wear it.

Italic comment is mine to express what the author means.